# JSON / JavaScript - find matching values, make them into keys and create new, consolidated object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping

In vanilla JavaScript, how would I find unique locations from this object and make them keys, and place all items with that location as values. (can install lodash if necessary).

So this:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "cat"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "porch"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "dog"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "porch"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "snake"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "forest"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "bird"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "forest"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "beer"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "fridge"
    }
  }
]
```

Becomes this:

```
[
  {
    "porch": [
      {
        "id": "cat"
      },
      {
        "id": "dog"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "forest": [
      {
        "id": "snake"
      },
      {
        "id": "bird"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fridge": [
      {
        "id": "beer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[PEN](https://codepen.io/kirkbross/pen/ZEbZrOr)

// modified desired result

```
[
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "porch",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "cat"
        },
        {
          "title": "dog"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "forest",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "snake"
        },
        {
          "title": "bird"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "fridge",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "beer"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let obj = [
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "cat"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "porch"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "dog"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "porch"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "snake"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "forest"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "bird"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "forest"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "beer"
    },
    "location": {
      "id": "fridge"
    }
  }
]

let result = {};

obj.forEach(({item, location}) => {
   if(!result[location.id]) result[location.id] = []
    result[location.id].push({title: item.id})
})
result = Object.keys(result).map(key => ({
    "location": {
      "name": key,
      "items": result[key]
    }
  }))
```

`result` contains required output.

Comment: Mohi Gawande Thank you, but that didn't work for me. The result array should only have 3 items with keys `"porch"`, `"forest"`, and `"fridge"`

Comment: Modified answer. Thanks.

Comment: Mohit Gwande Thank you, that did it! :)